# Gulp and Critical CSS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined

Tags: css, sass, gulp, critical-css

I'm running my build in Gulp and keep getting the following error in my terminal when it comes to generating my critical css files.

```
[08:47:29] -> Generating critical CSS: https://example.com/ -> ./templates/index_critical.min.css
[08:47:43] TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-type' of undefined
```

1. What does the error mean?
2. How do I solve the error?
3. If this is a syntax issue in my gulp file - is there way to find the line and reference to the issue either in the terminal when running the command or by using a validator?

Below is the gulp task for the critical css along with the tasks for processing the css and sass files which it references.

```
// scss - build the scss to the build folder, including the required paths, and writing out a sourcemap
gulp.task("scss", () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Compiling scss");
    return gulp.src(pkg.paths.src.scss + pkg.vars.scssName)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe($.sass({
                includePaths: pkg.paths.scss
            })
            .on("error", $.sass.logError))
        .pipe($.cached("sass_compile"))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.build.css));
});


// css task - combine & minimize any distribution CSS into the public css folder, and add our banner to it
gulp.task("css", ["scss"], () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Building css");
    return gulp.src(pkg.globs.distCss)
        //.pipe(purgecss({
        //    content: [pkg.paths.templates + '*.twig']
        //  }))
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.newer({dest: pkg.paths.dist.css + pkg.vars.siteCssName}))
        .pipe($.print())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe($.concat(pkg.vars.siteCssName))
        .pipe($.if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            $.cssnano({
                discardComments: {
                    removeAll: true
                },
                discardDuplicates: true,
                discardEmpty: true,
                minifyFontValues: true,
                minifySelectors: true
            })
        ))
        .pipe($.header(banner, {pkg: pkg}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.dist.css))
        .pipe($.filter("**/*.css"))
        .pipe($.livereload());
});

// Process the critical path CSS one at a time
function processCriticalCSS(element, i, callback) {
    const criticalSrc = pkg.urls.critical + element.url;
    const criticalDest = pkg.paths.templates + element.template + "_critical.min.css";

    let criticalWidth = 1200;
    let criticalHeight = 1200;
    if (element.template.indexOf("amp_") !== -1) {
        criticalWidth = 600;
        criticalHeight = 19200;
    }
    $.fancyLog("-> Generating critical CSS: " + $.chalk.cyan(criticalSrc) + " -> " + $.chalk.magenta(criticalDest));
    $.critical.generate({
        src: criticalSrc,
        dest: criticalDest,
        penthouse: {
            blockJSRequests: false,
            forceInclude: pkg.globs.criticalWhitelist
        },
        inline: false,
        ignore: [],
        css: [
            pkg.paths.dist.css + pkg.vars.siteCssName,
        ],
        minify: true,
        width: criticalWidth,
        height: criticalHeight
    }, (err, output) => {
        if (err) {
            $.fancyLog($.chalk.magenta(err));
        }
        callback();
    });
}

// critical css task
gulp.task("criticalcss", ["css"], (callback) => {
    doSynchronousLoop(pkg.globs.critical, processCriticalCSS, () => {
        // all done
        callback();
    });
});

// Lean Production build
gulp.task("leanbuild", ["set-prod-node-env", "static-assets-version", "criticalcss"]);
```

Comment: I also faced the same problem ..Did you found the solution.please share if any

Comment: This happens if the `src` param you pass into `critical` is invalid, and returns no response.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the `src` param you pass into `critical` is invalid, and returns no response.